# The "Who_Is()" function output is not showing in the tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to print the Who Is output to the tkinter window, but the output is displaying on the VS Code terminal.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import  *
from time import strftime
import whois # pip3 install python-whois

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x800')
root.title('Who Is')  # Adding Title
menubar = Menu(root)  # Creating Menubar

lookup = "example.com"
def Who_Is():
        res = whois.whois(lookup)
        print("[+] Domain: ", res.domain)
        print("[+] Organization: ", res.get('org'))

# Adding File Menu and Commands
recon = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Recon', menu=recon)
recon.add_command(label='Who Is Lookup', command=lambda: Who_Is())
recon.add_separator()
recon.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.destroy)

root.config(menu=menubar)
mainloop()
```

Comment: That's what print() does. You need to create a GUI widget (e.g., a label or a text) and use its methods to display the text.

Comment: Try change `recon.add_command(label='Who Is Lookup', command = Who_Is)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the removal of `lambda` from `menu` it served no purpose.

I've created a `tkinter` `Text` widget to output your results.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import  *
from time import strftime
import whois # pip3 install python-whois


root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x800')
root.title('Who Is')  # Adding Title
menubar = Menu(root)  # Creating Menubar

lookup = "example.com"
def Who_Is():
    res = whois.whois(lookup)
    text.insert( 'insert', f"[+] Domain: {res.domain}\n" )
    text.insert( 'insert', "[+] Organization: {res.get( 'org' )}\n" )

# Adding File Menu and Commands
recon = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Recon', menu=recon)
recon.add_command(label='Who Is Lookup', command = Who_Is )
recon.add_separator()
recon.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.destroy)

text = Text( root )
text.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.config(menu=menubar)
mainloop()
```